# Accessing headers of body part in multipart mail in Outlook using C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, multipart

I am trying to extract the headers of the body part of a multipart mail message in Outlook. The raw message (which I have not been able to get from my code) looks something like this:

```
Return-Path: ...
Received: ...
From: ...
Content-Type: multipart/signed; boundary="Apple-Mail=_06FDFEBB-366E-4B1E-AA7F-F5DDEC13FD03"; protocol="application/pgp-signature"; micalg=pgp-sha512
Subject: ...
Message-Id: ...
Date: ...
To: ...
Mime-Version: ...
X-Mailer: ...


--Apple-Mail=_06FDFEBB-366E-4B1E-AA7F-F5DDEC13FD03
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii

...

--Apple-Mail=_06FDFEBB-366E-4B1E-AA7F-F5DDEC13FD03
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename=signature.asc
Content-Type: application/pgp-signature;
    name=signature.asc
Content-Description: Message signed with OpenPGP using GPGMail

...

--Apple-Mail=_06FDFEBB-366E-4B1E-AA7F-F5DDEC13FD03--
```

I have replaced some of the none relevant parts by dots. The headers I am trying to get are the ones under the first boundary. So this is the part I am looking for:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii
```

However, if I could get the entire part between the boundaries, that would also be fine as I could parse it myself.

So far, I have only been able to get the headers at the top of the message (so from `Return-Path` until `X-Mailer`). 
I was able to do that using a `PropertyAccessor in the following way:

```
mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
```

In this case `mailItem` is my `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` instance.

So, what my question comes down to: How can I get the headers under the first boundary, or any bigger part of the message that contains them?

Answer (score 1):

For signed messages, Outlook preserves the signed message body (with full MIME data) in an attachment called `smime.p7m` (it's always called smime, even if it's actually PGP/MIME). Unfortunately, Outlook hides this from you, transparently unpacking the signed message and displaying it instead. There's no way, using the Outlook Object Model, to get the actual message body.

However, if you're willing to call MAPI directly (easiest from native code, but can be done from .NET if you're not afraid of some nasty COM interop), you can get the `multipart/signed` body - both the signature and the complete signed part - as follows:

Starting from the Outlook `MailItem`, get the `MAPIOBJECT` property. This is actually a MAPI `IMessage`. Cast it to an `IMAPISecureMessage` (.NET will handle this as a `QueryInterface` behind the scenes). Call `GetBaseMessage()` on this IMAPISecureMessage (the only documented function), which returns another `IMessage`. This is the "real" message, the one with the `smime.p7m` attachment. Unfortunately, there's no way to put this back into OOM, so you have to continue using MAPI. By calling the functions on `IMessage`, you can get the attachment, then get its data. You'll need to parse the MIME parts, at least enough to get the signed part without its headers, outer boundaries, or of course the signature part. Verify that signed part (*without* decoding its internal parts, if any, or decoding quoted-printable or anything like that) against the signature blob.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I stopped working on this a long time ago. I am no longer able to verify if this works for me, but I hope it can still help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

`PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property` is the only thing you can get. Outlook does not store the full MIME source of the original message.

You can see what is available in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.

Comment: The code I showed already got the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property. Thanks for the OutlookSpy tip, but I have not found the correct headers there. Does this mean it's simply not possible? This would mean I cannot verify the PGP signature of multipart messages in Outlook.

Comment: Does Outlook see these messages as signed/encrypted?

Comment: I think it does. It does show the little certificate sign on the mail, but is there any way to be sure about this?

Comment: Signed/encrypted messages are different - the original MIME is stored in the p7m attachment. To see it in OutlookSpy, click the IMAPIFolder button, go to the GetContentsTable tab, open the message from there. If you click IMessage button, OutlooikSpy retrieves the MAPIOBJECT property from the currently selected message, but Outlook returns a fake IMessage object for the encrypted/signed messages.

Comment: I have found the message in there and its class is MultipartSigned. I didn't find the p7m attachment or the headers I'm looking for yet.

Comment: So how exactly did you look at the message? What do you see?

Comment: I followed the steps you gave and have a window with IMessage - my subject as the title. It can display properties of the message and also has tabs for GetAttachmentTable, GetRecipientTable, etcetera. In the attachment table, there is only one attachment with a mime tag `multipart/signed`. Most of the information is not found however, so I don't know what it's called for example.

Comment: That's the attachment you want. What else did you expect to find?

Comment: I expected to find the actual headers of the signed part of the message or something containing them. Am I missing something or is there no data in that location that can help verifying the signature?

Comment: Which MIME headers exactly? Would you not need to look in the attachment data to extract any information?

Comment: The `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii` part from my question. I've got the attachment itself. Obtaining the text for which it's the signature is the problem since it includes the headers I just mentioned.

Comment: I do not use PGP, but usually the message body and the attachments are embedded inside the signature file.

Comment: For PGP, the signature requires the message/document to be able to verify it. The signature is not self contained.

Comment: In this case you are out of luck I am afraid as Outlook does not preserve the original MIME envelope.